# StackOverflow error on unit testing API controllers?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, stack-overflow

I'm working on a Spring Boot MVC project and I'm getting the following error when unit testing my CRUD controllers :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:840)
at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(Throwable.java:832)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:55)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:60)

java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:834)
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:247)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter.subjoinSTEPArray(ThrowableProxyConverter.java:216)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter.recursiveAppend(ThrowableProxyConverter.java:161)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter.recursiveAppend(ThrowableProxyConverter.java:168)
```

Here's one of the controllers unit test, the others follow the same logic.

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

@Test
public void deletarPessoa_quandoDelete() throws Exception {
    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
    pessoa.setNome("Test Nome");
    pessoa.setId(89L);
    doNothing().when(pessoaRepository).delete(pessoa);
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/pessoas/" + pessoa.getId().toString())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
}
```

What could this be? I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

EDIT : here's the controller, it basically calls for the repo to delete a Pessoa object

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deletar(@ApiParam(value = "ID", example = "1") @PathVariable Long id) {
    Pessoa pessoaDeletada = pessoaRepository.getOne(id);
    pessoaRepository.delete(pessoaDeletada);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something related to your logging system definitions. Can you re-try running the tests with default logback definitions?

Comment: I haven't done anything related to that, not sure what you're talking about

Comment: @GabrielPulga I have a similar issue but I couldn't fix it. Can you help me if you solve the issue? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-spring-security-servicetest-and-controllertest-for