# Spring Boot Microservices - Spring Security - ServiceTest and ControllerTest for JUnit throwing java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-cloud

I have a problem in running any test method in service test and controller test in one of the spring boot microservices (order service).

After I completed service and controller , I tried to write their test methods but I have a problem in there.

How can I fix it?

Here is the security config of order service?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    //
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    private final JWTAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/order/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/order/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web)
                -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authenticate/signup", "/authenticate/login", "/authenticate/refreshtoken");
    }

}
```

Here is one of the test method of OrderServiceTest shown below

```
@DisplayName("Get Order - Success Scenario")
@Test
void test_When_Order_Success() {
    
    //Mocking
    Order order = getMockOrder();
    when(orderRepository.findById(anyLong()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(order));
    
    when(restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class
    )).thenReturn(getMockProductResponse());
    
    when(restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class
    )).thenReturn(getMockPaymentResponse());
    
    //Actual
    OrderResponse orderResponse = orderService.getOrderDetails(1);
    
    //Verification
    verify(orderRepository, times(1)).findById(anyLong());
    verify(restTemplate, times(1)).getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class);
    verify(restTemplate, times(1)).getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class);
    
    //Assert
    assertNotNull(orderResponse);
    assertEquals(order.getId(), orderResponse.getOrderId());
}
```

Here is one of the test method of OrderControllerTest shown below.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Place Order -- Success Scenario")
@WithMockUser(username = "User", authorities = { "ROLE_USER" })
void test_When_placeOrder_DoPayment_Success() throws Exception {

    OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
    String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleUser();

    MvcResult mvcResult
            = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeorder")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest)))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    String orderId = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(orderId));
    assertTrue(order.isPresent());

    Order o = order.get();
    assertEquals(Long.parseLong(orderId), o.getId());
    assertEquals("PLACED", o.getOrderStatus());
    assertEquals(orderRequest.getTotalAmount(), o.getAmount());
    assertEquals(orderRequest.getQuantity(), o.getQuantity());
}
```

Here is the error when I run any method of service test and controller shown below.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:861)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(Throwable.java:853)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:79)
    ...
    ...
```

**To run the app,**

1 ) Run Service Registery (Eureka Server)

2 ) Run config server

3 ) Run zipkin and redis through these commands shown below on docker

```
  docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
  docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis
```

4 ) Run api gateway

5 ) Run other services

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Here is the **result of the service test** screenshot : [Link](https://ibb.co/FwmdLLS)

Here is the **result of the controller test** screenshot : [Link](https://ibb.co/MZwD22Q)

Edited

Replace

```
@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

with

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> myAuthenticationProviders) {
        return new ProviderManager(myAuthenticationProviders);
}
```

in secuity config of order service.

Here is the error message shown below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/microservice/orderservice/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A parent AuthenticationManager or a list of AuthenticationProviders is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.microservice.orderservice.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A parent AuthenticationManager or a list of AuthenticationProviders is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A parent AuthenticationManager or a list of AuthenticationProviders is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.checkState(ProviderManager.java:138) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>(ProviderManager.java:129) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>(ProviderManager.java:117) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.microservice.orderservice.config.SecurityConfig.authenticationManager(SecurityConfig.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microservice.orderservice.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83744c5.CGLIB$authenticationManager$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microservice.orderservice.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83744c5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d59030c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.microservice.orderservice.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83744c5.authenticationManager(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250132/discussion-on-question-by-s-n-spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-contro).

Comment: @xerx593 How can I define CustomDetailService in order service as I defined in auth service. I also did the same process for other service. How can I do that? I found this link as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215#issuecomment-1263802532

Comment: Why there are so many steps to run the tests? I'd expect the test to be self-contained and maybe just require docker to be running. I'd suggest you to simplify your test implementation and maybe provide a minimal, reproducible sample.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I defined zipkin and redis in api gateway and all these are running on docker. I think there is a problem in security config part in order service. I hope you can help me.

Comment: I think you should isolate your order service in order to figure out the problem. I doubt that zipkin, redis and API gateway had something to do with that. If it is possible, mock those external services in the test scenario.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio There is no problem in zipkin and redis part in api gateway. My problem is related with Spring security in order service. I think there can be authentication manager problem in security config in order service. As I still couldn't fix it, I asked it to you.

Comment: @DaShaun As I couldn't fix it, I think you can help me fix my issue which I'ven't fixed for nearly one week.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I still couldn't fix the the issue. Is it possible to help me?

Comment: Can you please see this answer and check if it makes sense for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694980/authenticationmanager-authenticate-throws-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-w/74706573#74706573

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I edited my post. Can you look through it if you don't mind?

Comment: It seems to me that you didn’t read my answer on that question with attention. If you are not using AuthenticationProvider you should probably use the UseDetailsService to create a DaoAuthenticationProvider

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I already defined UseDetailsService in auth service. My issue is in order service as it is a spring cloud example. How can I define UseDetailsService  in order service?

Comment: If your order service is a resource server it shouldn’t have any kind of authentication mechanism, just a validation of the token (I’m assuming you are using JWT). In summary, you should not need an AuthenticationManager at all

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I use JWT in order service. What should I do SecurityConfig as I use preAuthorized annotation in ordercontroller?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Is it possible to share the response if you don't mind?

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, it is your requirement. I’d say that you should validate the token, retrieve whatever user information is in there (username, authorities) and set it into the SecurityContextHolder

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I removed authenticationManager from security config.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Can you look through my another issue not calling another service ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737014/spring-boot-microservice-junit-controller-test-cannot-call-another-service-m

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely caused by declaring the AuthenticationManager as a `@Bean`. Try this in your test class:

```
@MockBean
private AuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
```

That said, the Spring Security team does not recommend exposing the AuthenticationManager in this way, see the comment in Spring issue [#29215](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215#issuecomment-1263802532)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you instead of relying on Spring to autowire the List, explicitly define your authentication providers as beans in your configuration.

like:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new MyAuthenticationProvider();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider) {
    return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(myAuthenticationProvider));
}
```